# Adding minutes using Carbon return wrong value

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to add minutes to the current time, and here's what I get.

**"2019-11-29T15:40:13.000000Z"**

Here's my code for adding minutes:

```
    $date=  Carbon::now('Asia/Manila');
    $now = ($date->format("H:i:s"));

    $timeout = Carbon::parse($now)->addMinutes(60);
    return $timeout;
```

Assuming my current time is:
**14:44:23**

And adding 10 minutes to it will make it:
**15:44:23**

Comment: Okay i returned it to adding 60 minutes. Is there any way to get the new time(which is added by 60 minutes) as a string?

Comment: as what string? you know there is an entire documentation page for this carbon library? https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$date = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);
$now = $date->format("H:i:s");
return $now;
```